# How Normalization performing in Python?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Normalization always brings values between 0 & 1
When I'm normalizing -ve/+ve values or total -ve values using [preprocessing.normalization](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.normalize.html) in python then the normalized values are coming -ve? Why so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It all depends on the normalization function used. In general, normalization is bringing data between -1.0 to 1.0 or 0.0 to 1.0

Methods of Data Normalization –

```
-Decimal Scaling
-Min-Max Normalization
-z-Score Normalization(zero-mean Normalization)
```

Decimal Scaling Method For Normalization –

[image]

Example –

```
Let the input data is: -10, 201, 301, -401, 501, 601, 701

To normalize the above data,
Step 1: Maximum absolute value in given data(m): 701
Step 2: Divide the given data by 1000 (i.e j=3)

Result: The normalized data is: -0.01, 0.201, 0.301, -0.401, 0.501, 0.601, 0.701
```

Min-Max Normalization –

[image]

Min(A), Max(A) are the minimum and maximum absolute value of A respectively.
v’ is the new value of each entry in data.
v is the old value of each entry in data.

Z-score normalization –

[image]

v’, v is the new and old of each entry in data respectively. σA, A is the standard deviation and mean of A respectively.

Comment: If this is about sklearn , then in that case the default normalization function in sklearn is L2.http://mathworld.wolfram.com/L2-Norm.html